# How would we proceed to determine the chromatic polynomial and the chromatic number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

**Question:**

Being provided with the graph below:

[Given Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFM69.jpg)

How should we go about finding its the chromatic polynomial and chromatic number? How would its minimal proper coloring look like?

I am thinking that we should be making use of p(G, λ )= p(Ge, λ) - p(Ge', λ) here.

If anyone could kindly assist me on how to go about solving it, and providing me with a set of detailed steps required to solve it, it would be more appreciated.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do it without using that equation (usually written like $p(G,\lambda)=p(G-e,\lambda)-p(G/e,\lambda)$), using known properties of chromatic polynomials. Can you regularly color it with 0, 1, 2 colors? Probably not, so it's $p(G,\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)(\lambda^2+a\lambda+b)$ (5 nodes meaning degree 5, leading coefficient 1). Moreover, it must start like $\lambda^5-8\lambda^4+\ldots$ (8 edges), what can you conclude concerning the value of $a$? Have you tried to color it with 3 colors? Then, you must have found there are 6 ways to do that, and $p(G,3)=6$ gives you the value of $b$.